# Sending URL request resulting in invalid JSON

Tags: javascript

I have this string with two variables inserted inside it

```
URL='https://bla.com/api/multicomplete?data={"query":"' + title_text + " " + city_name + '"}';
```

Sometime, `title_text` includes some wacky characters (&, $, letters like đ etc..) and it results in something like this:

```
title_text = 'Airport Hotel Park & Fly Sofia'

...?data={"query":"Airport%20Hotel%20Park%20&%20Fly%20Sofija",...
```

I can assume that that is because I have `%20&%20` in `URL`, and indeed when I remove `&%20` (& space), then I get no errors.

So I have tried this method:

```
JSON.stringfy(title_text)
```

to let me send those characters via URL, but it doesn't work. Is there a good method to escape those special characters in that long string? I don't feel like removing them for good, I feel so dirty thinking of it.

Comment: why don't you consider sending data in body  with POST request ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey This request is GET request made on one server, specified by their API. It needs to be a GET.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use URI Encoding using `encodeURI()` to solve this problem.
You can do `JSON.stringify` and concatenate with the base url just like you've already done.

Comment: Do you mean like `title_text2 = encodeURI(title_text)` and then
`URL2 = JSON.stringify(URL)`?

Comment: I don't follow you. Sorry, can you edit your post using my example to show me what you mean? I stringify the whole string, then I encode it?

Comment: Did you mean: `URL2 = JSON.stringify(URL)`, and then
`URL2 = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(URL2))`?

Comment: Yes that’s what I meant.. sorry I’m not on my laptop